# Why does my link append an underscore at "random" position

Tags: html, css

Using only HTML and CSS, when I use the `a` tag it is prefixing it with an `_`

I was thinking I had used the `content` tag some where, but to my surprise, it persists in a **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/g8wb2nvf/3/)**

```
<section>
    <h3>Activity</h3>
    <a href="#">
           <div class="activity">
            <div>Some</div>
            <div>> 198 days?</div>  <!-- why does this render as _> 198 days? -->

            <div>Progressing</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">> does not have underscore despite having > </a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.activity {
    background: #3ea18f;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
.activity div {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

RESULT

[image]

Removing the `a` tag resolves the issue but, I need the `a` tag

Likewise, removing the CSS `.activity div` also removes the `_` but obviously I need the style

Same issue persists if I use `<div>&gt; 198 days?</div>`

Comment: Are you using literal '>' and '<'? try using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_entities.htm

Comment: @user993553, I'm aware of that, sorry I didn't make it clear though - same issue persists

Comment: It's the links text-decoration, but why do you need a lot of html inside a a?

Comment: What you see it the underscore of the link you create. You could remove it by setting the `text-decoration` to `none` for the link surrounding your `div`

Comment: @user993553, that is not relevant. HTML5 spec supports this (`div` within `a` tag). Therefore I need to find out why.

Comment: @t.niese is correct, the reasoning is that to ensure that `>` character is displayed correctly in HTML five I hazard a guess that the character replace occurs with a space, which is underscored. Maybe because it is next to another `>` character.

Comment: @t.niese, hmmmmm this is right, but, why is it there only and not on all the text? The entire thing is a link

Comment: apologies, I was looking at the HTML4.01 markup

Comment: @Martin in html5 an `a` element is described as [transparent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#transparent-content-models). As of that it is allowed to contain `div`. and also the `>` is not the actual problem, you can replace the `>` with a `.`  and have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it this behaviour is intended or if it is a rendering bug.

In front of the `div` with the `_` there is a space because you have a new line, and if you add an `outline`  around all elements ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8wb2nvf/5/)) you see that the `_` is between the two elements.

If you add another element ([next fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8wb2nvf/6/)) you see that there is another `_`. So the underscore appears between all `inline-block` elements in the row.

The problem is not related to `>`.

To get around this problem without changing the rest of the appearance you might add `text-decoration` to `none` to the surrounding `a`.

You don't have a `> does not have underscore despite having >` in front because there is no space between the `<a href="#">` and the `> does not`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<section>
    <h3>Activity</h3>
    <a href="#">
           <div class="activity"><div>Some</div><div>> 198 days?</div><div>Progressing</div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <br />
    <a href="#">> does not have underscore despite having > </a>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y4zpgkfe/